# equivariant stable class of quaternionic Hopf fibration in RO(G)-degrees of ADE-type

Tags: rt.representation-theory, stable-homotopy, ade-classifications

Does the quaternionic Hopf fibration possibly represent a *non-torsion* element in the $G$-equivariant stable homotopy groups of spheres, for $G$ a finite subgroup of $SO(3)$ and in RO(G)-degree being its canonical 3d representation?

For the complex Hopf fibration the analog is true, as far as I see: In

- Shôrô Araki, Kouyemon Iriye, *Equivariant stable homotopy groups of spheres with involutions*. I, Osaka J. Math. Volume 19, Number 1 (1982), 1-55. ([Euclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200774828))

it is shown (theorem 8.7 i) that the complex Hopf fibration -- canonically regarded as a representative for a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded stable homotopy group of spheres in $RO(G)$-degree being the canonical 1-dimensional representation of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ -- is a non-torsion generator.

In this case the construction of the $\mathbb{Z}/2$-equivariant structure is induced, via the Hopf construction, from (on top of their p. 24) the $\mathbb{Z}/2$-equivariance of the product operation on complex numbers with respect to complex conjugation.

Analogously, the product operation on quaternions is of course $SO(3)$-equivariant, again with respect to the canonical action on their imaginary part. So it would seem that restricting this to any finite subgroup $G$ of $SO(3)$ and then applying the Hopf construction to the quaternions will yield a $G$-equivariant quaternionic Hopf fibration that represents an element in the $G$-equivariant stable homotopy groups of spheres in $RO(G)$-degree the corresponding 3d rep. (Right?)

For which choice of $G \hookrightarrow SO(3)$, if any, is this element non-torsion?

Or more generally, what is known about equivariant stable homotopy groups of spheres in what one might call  RO(G)-degrees of ADE type?

Comment: Just a remark: to detect non-torsion classes in equivariant stable homotopy theory, you need *rational* e.s.h.t.  For *finite* groups, r.e.s.h.t is supposed to be equivalent to the homotopy theory of chain complexes of rational Mackey functors on the group; and its homotopy category is just equivalent to graded rational Mackey functors.  That is: it's all just algebra.  So the answer to your question is very amenable to solution by calculation.  I have no idea who (if anyone) has done these calculations, or what they look like ...

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I need to get into contact with David Barnes http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rational+equivariant+stable+homotopy+theory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the Hopf construction gives a non-torsion class when G is dihedral or exceptional, but probably not when G is cyclic.

Non equivalently, we can perform Hopf constructions on the 0, 1, 3, and 7 spheres.  Only the 0 sphere gives a non torsion class in stable homotopy.

Suppose $G$ acts on our sphere, preserving the multiplication, with fixed points $(S^n)^G$ also a sphere $S^k$.  If $H: S^{2n+1} \to S^{n+1}$ is the Hopf map, then the restriction of $H$ to $G$ fixed points is also a Hopf map $H': S^{2k+1} \to S^{k+1}$.  If $k=0$, then $H'$ is stably non-torsion (non-equivariantly), and therefore so is $H$ in the  $G$ equivariant stable category.

Conversely, if $k>0$, I think $H$ must be stably torsion $G$ equivariantly: the rational stable equivariant homotopy type of a space $X$ (for finite groups) is (I think) completely determined by the $H^*(X^K, Q)$ as $WK=NK/K$ modules, where $K$ ranges over the conjugacy classes of subgroups of $G$, and rational stable maps are all detected by these groups.

Comment: Thanks! I get it. Just to amplify: your argument says that a Hopf generator should become non-torsion equivariantly whenever the fixed points of the action reduce it to a 1-sphere; and for n = 3 this is case for all the ADE finite groups except the cyclic ones. Incidentally, that is consistent with Araki-Iriye'82 cited above: their prop. 10.1 and theorem 10.11 says that Z/2-equivariantly the quaternionic Hopf fibration is still torsion of order 24.

Comment: For what it's worth, the exclusion of the cyclic ADE groups actually matches the situation in the application that motivates me here: one sees the same exclusion on p. 3 of arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9812205 (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/G2+manifold#WithADEOrbifoldStructure).

Comment: I have now written out a proof, using the above argument and appealing to Greenlees-May decomposition and tom Dieck splitting: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quaternionic+Hopf+fibration#ClassInEquivariantStableHomotopyTheory